# how to search in several documents a property that has children, without knowing the id of the document

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mogodb, and I have a collection with n documents.

```
db.test.insertMany(
    [
        {
        "name":"homer",
        "house": {
            "floor": 1,
            "persons": ["pedro","pablo","jacinto"]
        }

        },
        {
            "name":"marge",
            "house": {
                "floor": 2,
                "persons": ["jose"]
            }

        }
    ]
```

)

I would like to search within my collection the elements where the "floor" property is equal to 2. how can I do it?

```
db.test.find( { house: {floor:2 } }   not works for me
{ house: { $elemMatch : { "floor" : 1 }}} not works for me
```

this does not work for me, maybe it's because I need to specify the id, but in my case I have to search specifically for an attribute without previously knowing the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.test.find({ "house.floor": 2 })
```

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621546/return-only-the-last-level-of-the-embedded-property-that-is-searched-in-a-docume