# return only the last level of the embedded property that is searched in a document

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents.

```
db.test.find({"house.floor":1})



    db.test.insertMany([{
        "name":"homer",
        "house": {
            "floor": 1,
            "room": 
            {
                "bed": "bed_pink",
                "chair":"chair_pink"
            }
        }

    },
    {
        "name":"marge",
        "house": {
            "floor": 1,
            "room": 
            {
                "bed": "bed_blue",
                "chair":"chair_red"
            }
        }

    }]
    )    

     db.test.find({"house.room.bed":"bed_blue"})
```

I want to return only the value of the last level of my search. in this case:

```
            {
                "bed": "bed_blue",
                "chair":"chair_red"
            }
```

the answer I get, is the whole document, I want to advance to a certain level of the query. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for it

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $match: { "house.room.bed":"bed_blue" } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$house.room" } }
])
```

Comment: thanks! >db.test3.agregate([{ $match: { "house.room.bed":"bed_blue" } },{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$house.room" } }])
2019-04-10T22:16:55.634+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:21 I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` together with `$match` and `$project` for this as follows:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "house.room.bed": "bed_blue"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "bed": "$house.room.bed",
      "chair": "$house.room.chair"
    }
  }
])
```

Further, you can modify the `$project` part as needed.

Here is a demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fvll0LFIvQy